# Common ui base for dialogs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, user-interface

In Qt widget application, I'd like to have a common base view for all my dialogs, so that I could inherit other classes from it.

This "base/common" view would contain initially a set of buttons at the bottom and a custom frame with data at the top. A place in the middle would be used by derived classes for placing view-specific contents. If the common dialog style changes in the future, changes will be applied in one class only.

Is there any way to use such approach in Qt, since ui files are processed with 'uic' to create classes? Ideally would be to not to lose the ability of using the gui designer, at least for the derived classes.
Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your "base view" as its own ui file with a big QFrame in the middle with nothing in it and name it contentsFrame.  Then create your other widgets you want to place inside the empty contentsFrame in designer.

Now you have a couple options.  You can have both open side by side in designer, click on your contents widget, select all, and drag everything to your contentsFrame.  Then just hit save as and save it as a different widget.  If you aren't afraid to leave designer for a tiny bit, you can add your contents widget to the base widget in code.  Either way, make sure you are setting the layout for your contentsFrame or everything will look like garbage.